# How do I pass a javascript variable coming from PHP object to javascript back to PHP to be used as an Index in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm using Laravel 8 and creating a FullCalendar where when you click the event, more details can be seen via the modal that pops up.

```
events:[
    @foreach($events as $event)          
      { 
        id: '{{$loop->index}}', title: '{{$event->patientInfo->first_name}} - {{$event->patientTreatment->treatment}} - {{$event->patientService->service}}', 
        start: '{{$event->appointment}}', 
        resourceId: '{{$event->id}}', 
        color: '{{$event->branches->text_color}}', 
      },
    @endforeach
    ],
```

I'm retrieving the events Index from the    `id: '{{$loop->index}}'`

```
eventClick: function(info) {
  var event_data = info.event.id;
},
```

I've checked it through `alert(event_data);` The alert verifies it's working thus far. Now I'm trying to get it so I can use it in PHP to get data and relational data beginning with this way

```
$event_data = $events[var_event_index_here];
$event_data->first_name; $event_data->phone;     
....etc
```

I have no idea how to use that javascript variable for the index. I've searched different ways of retrieving it, but this is what I've tried to test

```
eventClick: function(info) {

  var event_data = info.event.id;

  <?php
    $test= "<script>document.writeln(event_data);</script>";
  ?>

  var dialog =  '<div id="dialog" class="modalTitle"  style="z-index:9999">{{$test}}</div>';

  $('body').append(dialog);
  $('#dialog').dialog({modal:true, title: "TITLE"});
},
```

[This is the result I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byad3.png)

Comment: Use `{!! $test !!}` instead of `{{ $test }}`. Or, read the documentation on how `.blade.php` templating works: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data. That being said, this is unlikely to work as `event_data` is a JS variable, and that `<?php ... ?>` block runs long before `event_data` is available. You should probably be using an AJAX request of some kind to handle this.

Comment: @TimLewis Hi thanks.  You're right, that doesn't seem to work. I'll look into doing an AJAX request of some sort

Comment: Sounds good  It could work if `event_data` was a PHP variable, like `<script>document.writeln('{{ $event_data }}')</script>`, but yeah; mixing PHP and JS only really works if everything is in PHP variables, since that will end up parsed into JS as `<script>document.writeln('content of event_data variable')</script>`